# Syntax error in elif prevents further execution

Tags: python, syntax

Why am I am getting a `SyntaxError` in the following code?

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-7ae98456e846>", line 23
    elif o[0]=='-t':
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
Options = 'h:u:d:e:n:p:o:i:z:a:t'
opts = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], Options)[0]

for o in opts:
    if o[0] == '-n':
        Name = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-o':
        Organization = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-h':
        ApigeeHost = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-d':
        Directory = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-e':
        Environment = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-p':
        BasePath = o[1]
    elif o[0] == '-u':
        UserPW = o[1]    
    elif o[0] == '-z':
        ZipFile = o[1]
    elif o[0]=='-a':
        ApiEnvUrl=o[1]
    elif o[0]=='-t':
        TargetApiEnvUrl=o[1]
    elif o[0]=='-i':
        ShouldDeploy=True
```

Comment: What kind of `syntaxError`?

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?  Just scanning it looks syntactically valid to me

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation uses both tabs and spaces.

[image]

(dots are spaces, arrows are tabs)

You should not mix tabs and spaces. You should choose only one or the other and use that exclusively (preferably spaces).

If you find yourself doing this often, your IDE or text editor may have a setting that will automatically insert spaces whenever you press the tab key. For instance, in Notepad++, it's in Settings->Preferences->Language Menu/Tab Settings->Replace by space.

Also, delete those asterisks. But I assume those aren't in your actual code.